# How I can use the exception in oracle for function without error

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I use the exception in my code , But I get error .please help me . my code is :

```
create or replace function persian_to_gregorian(p_persian varchar2) 
return date is
begin
 
  return to_date(
    'YYYYMMDD', 'nls_calendar=persian');
   EXCEPTION
         WHEN date format not recognized    THEN
         dbms_output.put_line('VALUE_ERROR has been occured.');
end;

select
persian_to_gregorian('14013102')
from dual;
```

Comment: there a fixed possibiliies see https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TTPLS/exceptions.htm#TTPLS196

Comment: @nbk but I cant know why the "date format not recognized " get error when i added to my code?why ? please help me . I am new in oracle .

Comment: you code must look like this https://dbfiddle.uk/hoFQKyRj

Answer (score 0):

In general, catching `OTHERS` is bad practice (as it hides all errors from the user). However, when you are wrapping a single built-in function that can throw many exceptions and you want to catch them all then that may be simplest:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION persian_to_gregorian(
  p_persian IN VARCHAR2
) RETURN DATE
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN TO_DATE(p_persian, 'YYYYMMDD', 'nls_calendar=persian');
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('VALUE_ERROR has been occured.');
    RETURN NULL;
END;
/
```

If you want to catch individual exceptions then you can use user-defined exceptions with `PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT`:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION persian_to_gregorian(
  p_persian IN VARCHAR2
) RETURN DATE
IS
  INVALID_YEAR EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(INVALID_YEAR, -1841);
  INVALID_MONTH EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(INVALID_MONTH, -1843);
  INVALID_DAY EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(INVALID_DAY, -1847);
BEGIN
  RETURN TO_DATE(p_persian, 'YYYYMMDD', 'nls_calendar=persian');
EXCEPTION
  WHEN INVALID_YEAR THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('VALUE_ERROR has been occured.');
    RETURN NULL;
  WHEN INVALID_MONTH THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('VALUE_ERROR has been occured.');
    RETURN NULL;
  WHEN INVALID_DAY THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('VALUE_ERROR has been occured.');
    RETURN NULL;
END;
/
```

But if there are other date-related exceptions then you will need to list them all (which, in this narrow case is why using `OTHERS` may be acceptable as there are probably going to be more cases than the 3 listed here).

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XVrqF6bR)

Comment: @MTO thanks a lot for your answering dear MTO :) .that the best way .